# How can I unpack multi-part archives (zip/rar) in Python?

Tags: python, raspbian, archive, unpack

I have a 2 GB archive (prefer .zip or .rar) file in parts (let's assume 100 parts x 20MB), and I am trying to find a way to unpack it properly. I started with a .zip archive; I had files like test.zip, test.z01, test.z02...test.99, etc. When I merge them in Python like this:

```py
for zipName in zips:
     with open(os.path.join(path_to_zip_file, "test.zip"), "ab") as f:
         with open(os.path.join(path_to_zip_file, zipName), "rb") as z:
             f.write(z.read())
```

and then, after merge, unpack it like thod"

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(path_to_zip_file, "test.zip"), "r") as zipObj:
     zipObj.extractall(path_to_zip_file)
```

I get errors, likr

> test.zip file isn't zip file.

So then I tried with a .rar archive. I tried to unpack just the first file to see if my code would intelligently look for and pick up the remaining archive fragments, but it did not. So again I merged the .rar files (just like in the .zip case), and then tried to unpack it by using `patoolib`:

```
patoolib.extract_archive("test.rar", outdir="path here")
```

When I do that, I get errors like:

> patoolib.util.PatoolError: could not find an executable program to extract format rar; candidates are (rar,unrar,7z)

After some work I figured out that these merged files are corrupted (I copied it and try to unpack normally on windows using WinRAR, and encountered some problems). So I tried other ways to merge for example using `cat` `cat test.part.* >test.rar`, but those don't help.

How can I merge and then unpack these archive files properly in Python?

Comment: You can't simply append two files and assume that it is a valid new file. The idea is that the unzip / unrar tool will handle multiple files on its own when giving it the first file of such a set.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I tried that. Just archive libs doesn't support that kind of action. Also that's why cat doesn't work probably part of this zip/rar parts has some headers that should be skipped etc.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi problem is that you don't understand that. Creating parts isn't important in that case (they were created manualy by winrar) Like I said there is problem with merging parts.

Comment: I totally agree with @MisterMiyagi. How did you end up with such files in the first place? They might not be ZIP files at all. I can rename a DOC file to Z01 and you will never be able to uncompress, no matter how hard you try.

Comment: As I said in my first comment: you probably don't have to merge at all.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have to merge multipart files becasue libs like zipfile doesn't support extracting multiparts and cause errors like zip isn't zip file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Calling 7z out of python

1. rename the `.zip` to `.zip.001` and `.z01` to `zip.002` and so on.
2. call 7z on the `001` ( `7z x test.zip.001` )

```py
import subprocess
cmd = ['7z', 'x', 'test.zip.001']
sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

### CAT

`cat test.zip* > test.zip` should also work, but not always imho. Tried it for single file and works, but failed with subfolders. Maintaining the right order is mandatory.

**Testing:**

```sh
7z -v1m a test.zip 12MFile
cat test.zip* > test.zip
7z t test.zip
>> Everything is Ok
```

Can't check with "official" WinRAR (does this even still exist?!) nor WinZIP Files.

### Merge File in Python

If you want to stay in python this works too (again for my 7z testfiles..):

```py
import shutil
import glob

with open('output_file.zip','wb') as wfd:
    for f in glob.glob('test.zip.*'): # Search for all files matching searchstring
        with open(f,'rb') as fd:
            shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd) # Concatinate
```

### Further remarks

- `pyunpack` (python frontend) with `patool` (python backend) and installed `unrar` or `p7zip-rar` (7z with the unfree rar-stuff) for linux or `7z` in windows can handle zip and rar (and many more) in python
- there is a `7z x -t` flag for explicitly set it as split archive (if file is not named 001 maybe helps). Give as e.g. `7z x -trar.split` or `7z x -tzip.split` or something.

Comment: first of all there is no part z00. Secondly first of all I checked that I merge sorted file (and what order that was). And I had good order ( I mean first zip then z01 etc). And still archive was corrupted

Comment: Ok sorry, I tested it and it works. With rars there is even less work because extends are the same just need to choose first part. Bounty for you

Comment: btw there is no 7z lib that support rar extends in python ?